# $SERVER["PHP_SELF"] with double value

Tags: php, fastcgi, iis-10

On a windows server 2016 with IIS 2010, I have manually installed an old version of PHP (5.2.4) for an old site. Currently, it is running through FastCGI.

All seems to working correctly except for this. The server variable PHP_SELF has a double value.

This is my CGI configuration in the php.ini file:

```
cgi.check_shebang_line: 1
cgi.fix_pathinfo: 0
cgi.force_redirect: 0
cgi.nph: 0
cgi.redirect_status_env: no value
cgi.rfc2616_headers: 0
fastcgi.impersonate: 1
fastcgi.logging: 1
```

I have spent many hours to search a solution on internet, but unfortunately without any usefull result.

Can you help me on this trouble?

Thanks in advance,
Lorenzo.

Comment: What do you mean by *"The server variable `PHP_SELF` has a double value"*?

Comment: when printing it ? what is the result you got ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wanted to advise php ini set:

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=0
```

But saw you turned off this option.
I think its bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=42523 and you can use [SCRIPT_NAME](http://ca.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Hi Konstantin. Thanks for this response. I am unable to adopt the suggested solution but I am focusing to find an alternative solution. However, I think that this answer is the right solution for this problem. Thanks again.